# How does Ubuntu One know my new password when I change it through the web form?

Tags: ubuntu-one, password

I changed my Ubuntu One password through the "edit personal details online" button.

Both my Windows and Ubuntu One installations continue to work without updating the login information.

I changed my password because I was worried someone else was using my account. But if their installations login info was also updated automatically it defeats the purpose of changing the password at all.

Comment: This would be a bug. The token should be revoked on the server when you change your password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu One is using something called [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).  It will have requested your authorization on the Ubuntu site the first time you set it up, but it did this in order to get tokens.  When Ubuntu One communicates with the servers, it uses these tokens to authenticate and authorize.  Whenever the app tries to perform an operation, it will use that token, and the Ubuntu One servers will know that the token represents you.  In other words, Ubuntu One is storing your 'consent', rather than your credentials.

This is a common method used in several applications, and it means a few things

1. The app doesn't store your username and password, so you don't have to worry about security leaks
2. You can revoke the token to stop the app from continuing to work.  You can check your tokens by [following these instructions](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-check-my-oauth-tokens/). You can also revoke your tokens on the Ubuntu site [here](https://login.ubuntu.com/+applications).

Comment: How can I revoke the token? The link on that subject on the page you linked to is broken.

Comment: Eek, didn't see that the Python script had become strange.  I've added another link to the post, which revokes the token remotely.  Your app will stop working, you will need to re-login so that Ubuntu One can grab a new token.